# Best way to loop node.js script on large array

Tags: node.js

I'm fetching an array of objects from a DB, and using their data in a heavy method, to create some SVG files.

```
MongoClient.connect(MONGO)
  .then((database) => {
    data = database
    db = database.db('apidatabase')
    return db.collection('Products')
      .find({
        owner: 'pingu',
      })
      .toArray()
  })
  .then((products) => {
    products.forEach((product, index) => {
      createFiles(product) // the heavy method
    })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log({ error })
    data.close()
  })
```

If I start my script for all the objects (I have more than 6000 of them), the scripts freezes, and nothing gets done. I have to slice my array, and get through them all by slices of 20 objects.

Is there a way to properly iterate though these objects, so that the script runs smoothly for all 6000 objects ?

Comment: You should find out how much memory each is consuming.  You likely shouldn't be loading them all and then process them after the fact, but rather iterate through each one (letting the previous get purged from memory).  Take a look at this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Comment: If you can use a 3rd party library, try Promise.map in bluebird. You can specify how many elements in the array you want to do in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You should fork `createFiles` function in Node.JS and process it. Refer [documentation](https://itnext.io/multi-threading-and-multi-process-in-node-js-ffa5bb5cde98) to understand, how you can fork and retrieve entire response back to your function.